# Update the list in the table depending on the selected value of dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a dynamic Dropdown with companies options and I have a table of companies information. I want that my table list change, when I change the company in the Dropdown of companies.
Furthermore, I know that I have to use JavaScript, but I don't have any skills with it. please help me.

That is my CSHTML

```
@page
@model Fachinformationsdienst_Kundenportal.Pages.Information_listModel
@{
}
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="inputState">Unternehmen</label>
        <select id="inputState" class="form-control" onchange="ChangeList(this)">
            <option selected>Wählen Sie die Firma aus...</option>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.companies.Count; i++)
            {
                <option>@Model.companies[i].FirmenKurzBezeichnung</option>
            }
        </select>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped" id="FachinfoTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nr.</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Letzte Änderung</th>
            <th scope="col">Aktuelle Version</th>
            <th scope="col">Auftrag</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.fachinfos.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@Model.fachinfos[i].FachinfoNummer</th>
                <td>@Model.fachinfos[i].FachinfoName</td>
                <td>@Model.fachinfos[i].Status</td>
                <td>@Model.fachinfos[i].Datum</td>
                <td>@Model.fachinfos[i].PdfVersion</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<script>
```

Model.cs

```
using Fachinformationsdienst_Kundenportal.Classes;
using Fachinformationsdienst_Kundenportal.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Fachinformationsdienst_Kundenportal.Pages
{
    public class Information_listModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<Company> companies;
        public List<Fachinfo> fachinfos = new List<Fachinfo>();

        public void OnGet()
        {
            companies = APIRequester.GetCompanies(User.Identity.Name);
            foreach (var company in companies)
            {
                fachinfos.AddRange(APIRequester.GetFachinfos(company.FirmenKurzBezeichnung));
            }
        }
        public List<Fachinfo> GetFachinfosByCompany(string company)
        {
            return APIRequester.GetFachinfos(company);
        }
    }
}
```

Company Class

```
namespace Fachinformationsdienst_Kundenportal.Models
{
    public class Company
    {
        public string FirmenKurzBezeichnung { get; set; }
        public string Rolle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Information Class

```
namespace Fachinformationsdienst_Kundenportal.Models
{
    public class Fachinfo
    {
        public int FachinfoNummer { get; set; }
        public string FachinfoName { get; set; }
        public string FirmenKurzBezeichnung { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string StatusText { get; set; }
        public string Datum { get; set; }
        public string PdfVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Partial View to display the fachinfos List, then, based on the dropdownlist selected value, use JQuery Ajax to dynamically update the partial view. Please refer the following code:

Create a _FachinfoPartial.cshtml partial view(without page model):

```
@model List<RazorSample.Models.Fachinfo>

<table class="table table-striped" id="FachinfoTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nr.</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Status</th>
            <th scope="col">Letzte Änderung</th>
            <th scope="col">Aktuelle Version</th>
            <th scope="col">Auftrag</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">@Model[i].FachinfoNummer</th>
                <td>@Model[i].FachinfoName</td>
                <td>@Model[i].Status</td>
                <td>@Model[i].Datum</td>
                <td>@Model[i].PdfVersion</td>
                <td>Thornton</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Update the Information_listModelModel.cshtml page as below (change the namespace ("RazorSample") to yours): using `<partial>` tag to render the partial view when page load, then, use JQuery Ajax to update the partial view based on the selected company.

```
@page
@model RazorSample.Pages.Information_listModelModel
@{
}
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="inputState">Unternehmen</label>
    <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Wählen Sie die Firma aus...</option>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.companies.Count; i++)
        {
            <option>@Model.companies[i].FirmenKurzBezeichnung</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
<div id="fachinfoContainer"> 
    <partial name="_FachinfoPartial" model="@Model.fachinfos" />
</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#inputState").change(function () {
                var selectcompany = "";
                if ($(this).val() != "Wählen Sie die Firma aus...") {
                    selectcompany = $(this).val();
                } 
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Information_listModel?handler=fachinfoPartial",
                    type: "Get",
                    data: { company: selectcompany },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#fachinfoContainer").html(""); //clear the fachinfo container.
                        $("#fachinfoContainer").html(result); //populate the container.
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

In the Information_listModel.cshtml.cs page, create a `OnGetFachinfoPartial` handler to return partial view.

```
public class Information_listModelModel : PageModel
{
    public List<Company> companies;
    public List<Fachinfo> fachinfos = new List<Fachinfo>();

    public void OnGet()
    {
        //companies = APIRequester.GetCompanies(User.Identity.Name);
        //foreach (var company in companies)
        //{
        //    fachinfos.AddRange(APIRequester.GetFachinfos(company.FirmenKurzBezeichnung));
        //}
        companies = repo.GetCompanies();
        foreach(var company in companies)
        {
            fachinfos.AddRange(repo.GetFachinfos(company.FirmenKurzBezeichnung));
        }

    }

    public PartialViewResult OnGetFachinfoPartial(string company)
    {
        //based on the selctedcompany to filter data, then return to the partial view.
        fachinfos = GetFachinfosByCompany(company);
        return Partial("_FachinfoPartial", fachinfos);
    }
    public List<Fachinfo> GetFachinfosByCompany(string company)
    {
        //return APIRequester.GetFachinfos(company);
        return repo.GetFachinfos(company);
    }
}
```

The following is the initial data:

```
public static class repo
{
    public static List<Company> GetCompanies()
    {
        return new List<Company>()
        {
            new Company(){ Rolle="admin", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Microsoft"},
            new Company(){ Rolle="user", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Google"},
            new Company(){ Rolle="admin", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Alibaba"},
            new Company(){ Rolle="user", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Amazon"},
            new Company(){ Rolle="admin", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Facebook"},
        };
    }

    public static List<Fachinfo> GetFachinfos(string company)
    {
        var fachinfolist = new List<Fachinfo>()
        {
            new Fachinfo(){ FachinfoNummer=101, FachinfoName="AA", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Microsoft", Status="Online", Datum= DateTime.Now.ToString()},
            new Fachinfo(){ FachinfoNummer=102, FachinfoName="BB", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Google", Status="Online", Datum= DateTime.Now.ToString()},
            new Fachinfo(){ FachinfoNummer=103, FachinfoName="CC", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Alibaba", Status="Online", Datum= DateTime.Now.ToString()},
            new Fachinfo(){ FachinfoNummer=104, FachinfoName="DD", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Amazon", Status="Online", Datum= DateTime.Now.ToString()},
            new Fachinfo(){ FachinfoNummer=105, FachinfoName="EE", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Facebook", Status="Online", Datum= DateTime.Now.ToString()},
            new Fachinfo(){ FachinfoNummer=106, FachinfoName="FF", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Microsoft", Status="Online", Datum= DateTime.Now.ToString()},
            new Fachinfo(){ FachinfoNummer=107, FachinfoName="GG", FirmenKurzBezeichnung="Google", Status="Online", Datum= DateTime.Now.ToString()},
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(company))
        {
            fachinfolist = fachinfolist.Where(c => c.FirmenKurzBezeichnung == company).ToList();
        }

        return fachinfolist;
    }
}
```

Then, the result like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi @AnasSadek, It seems that you are meeting the 404 error when using JQuery Ajax, in my sample, the handler name in the Information_listModelModel.cshtml.cs page is `OnGetFachinfoPartial()`, so the request url is `/Information_listModel?handler=fachinfoPartial`. According to the error message, it seems that the url is `https://localhost:44375/Information_listModel?handler=_fachinfoPartial&company=Pfizer%20PFE`, so the handler name should like this `OnGet_fachinfoPartial`, please check your code whether it is correct or not? If still not working, can you share the related handler method?

Comment: Hi, everything is OK, the Code works very good, the Problem was with the URL and I fixed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, can I use your AJAX to Update the Table without the Partial View? Can you help me please!

Comment: Yes, you can use Ajax to update the table content without using the partial view. But using this method, after getting the latest data, you have to loop through the data and create the table elements, then using the append method to add the table elements to the page. You can refer to [this sample](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-dynamic-HTML-Table-using-jQuery.aspx)